# tsql check if event has occurred within a certain frequency

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of failure events that occurred. I need to find out for example if it five failures were logged within two minutes.

```
Id  Created                  EventType  Description
1   2015-11-16 15:10:16      1         test
2   2015-11-16 15:12:17      1         test
3   2015-11-16 15:12:18      1         test
4   2015-11-16 15:12:19      1         test
5   2015-11-16 15:12:20      1         test
6   2015-11-16 15:13:16      1         test
7   2015-11-16 16:15:43      1         test
```

so in this example events 2-6 would be selected. I need to then select the start and end time of the period.

Don't even know where to begin as obviously it is comparing two rows. I thought about using a cursor but not sure if there is any clever grouping I could use.

Comment: Do you have SQL 2012 or higher?

Comment: If 7 happened at 2015-11-16 16:15:00 and 3 others occurred at 2015-11-16 16:15:01 what results should be returned? Because 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 would be inside a 2 minute window. So should there now be two groups: 2-6 and 6-10?

Comment: Imagine a second case. There is a constant stream of events every 30 seconds. So we we have 12:00:00, 12:00:30, 12:01:00, 12:01:30, 12:02:00, 12:02:30, 12:03:00, 12:03:30, 12:04:00, 12:04:30. So does this mean 1-5 and 6-10? Or 1-5, 2-6, 3-7, 4-8, 5-9 and 6-10? If you need to setup alerts and don't want more than 1 alert per 2 minute bucket then I think the first option would be best. However that might be more complex to do.

Comment: Voting to close.  You have been asked to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to initially select events 2-6:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.EventType, t1.Created AS StartTime, t3.EndTime
FROM mytable AS t1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 t2.Id, t2.Created 
   FROM mytable AS t2
   WHERE t1.EventType = t2.EventType AND
         t2.Id <> t1.Id AND
         ABS(DATEDIFF(ss, t1.Created, t2.Created)) <= 60 
   ORDER BY DATEDIFF(ss, t1.Created, t2.Created) DESC) AS t3(Id, EndTime)
```

**Output:**

```
Id  EventType   StartTime               EndTime
2   1           2015-11-16 15:12:17.000 2015-11-16 15:13:16.000
3   1           2015-11-16 15:12:18.000 2015-11-16 15:13:16.000
4   1           2015-11-16 15:12:19.000 2015-11-16 15:13:16.000
5   1           2015-11-16 15:12:20.000 2015-11-16 15:13:16.000
6   1           2015-11-16 15:13:16.000 2015-11-16 15:12:20.000
```

You can now check if the record bucket contains 5 rows or more and get first / last records using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.Id) AS StartID, 
       MAX(t3.Id) AS EndID, 
       t1.EventType, 
       MIN(t1.Created) AS StartTime, MAX(t3.EndTime) AS EndTime
FROM mytable AS t1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 t2.Id, t2.Created 
   FROM mytable AS t2
   WHERE t1.EventType = t2.EventType AND
         t2.Id <> t1.Id AND
         ABS(DATEDIFF(ss, t1.Created, t2.Created)) <= 120 
   ORDER BY DATEDIFF(ss, t1.Created, t2.Created) DESC) AS t3(Id, EndTime)
GROUP BY t1.EventType
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
```

**Output:**

```
StartID EndID   EventType   StartTime               EndTime
2       6       1           2015-11-16 15:12:17.000 2015-11-16 15:13:16.000
```

**Edit:**

An alternative way of doing it is by the use of a [**`Recursive CTE`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
;WITH CTE_RN AS (
   SELECT Id, EventType, Created,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Created) AS rn
   FROM mytable
), CTE_Buckets AS (
   -- Anchor member: Get first row from table
   SELECT Id, EventType, Created, CAST(1 AS BIGINT) AS row_num,
          1 AS bucket_num, 0 AS time_diff
   FROM CTE_RN
   WHERE rn = 1

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive member: Get next row. Reset time diff cumulative counter
   -- if time difference exceeds two minutes
   SELECT c1.Id, c1.EventType, c1.Created, c1.rn AS row_num, 
          -- All consecutive rows within the 2 minute time range fall within the same bucket
          bucket_num = CASE 
                          WHEN x.diff + time_diff > 120 THEN c2.bucket_num + 1
                          ELSE c2.bucket_num 
                       END,
          -- Calculate cummulative time diff. 
          time_diff = CASE 
                         WHEN x.diff + time_diff > 120 THEN 0
                         ELSE x.diff + time_diff
                      END
   FROM CTE_RN AS c1
   INNER JOIN CTE_Buckets AS c2 ON c1.rn = c2.row_num + 1
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(ss, c2.Created, c1.Created)) AS x(diff)
)   
SELECT MIN(Id) AS StartID, MAX(Id) AS EndID, 
       MIN(Created) AS StartTime, MAX(Created) AS EndTime
FROM CTE_Buckets
GROUP BY bucket_num   
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
```

This query handles multiple interval groups.

Comment: event id will always be 1 so yes will have to use rownumber

Comment: @DasDave You mean `EventType`? I was referring to the case of having more than one *groups* of events for the same `EventType`. Is that the case with you data?

Comment: sorry yes event type, but yes the problem is i will have more than one group.

Comment: @DasDave Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Giorgos we are running on sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

Not all of it but should get you started

```
select t1.ID, t2.ID, t1.Created, t2.Created, count(*) as ccount 
  from table t1 
  join table t2 
    on t2.ID <> t1.ID 
   and t2.Created > t1.Created  
   and DateDiff(minute, t2.Created, t1.Created) <= 2   
 group by t1.ID, t2.ID, t1.Created, t2.Created
having count(*) >= 5
```

If you know ID is going to be in order can use on t2.ID > t1.ID

That might not be the exact DateDiff syntax as I did it from memory

Let say you had 7 in a range.  This would report any (multiple) group of 5.  You need to be very specific on what you want.

Comment: I'm thinking along the same line. But   if id is going straight forward - it is possible to create join on t2.id = t1.id + 5

Comment: @Ingaz But you would still need the DateDiff so I am not sure it would go faster.  And it would kill if you have more than 5 in the time range.

Comment: If ids are going straight forward without lapses - it becomes possible to query without 'group by'. But the case of more than 5 - will give some false positives.

Comment: A lot is possible.  But don't know for sure ID is in order and don't know what they want if more then 5 occur in 2 minutes.